# Ruby: can't get bundler to work on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to install bundler via `gem install bundler`, everything works fine but then when I do `bundle install` I get:

> ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p385 on Mountain Lion.

I tried to reinstall many times following the hints on Stack Overflow but with no luck.

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have bundler in your PATH variable, check with with `echo $PATH`

If the directory containing the bundler is not there add it with `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bundler`

Comment: when I echo $PATH I get: 

/Users/[...]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin

then if ls on that folder I have bundle as well

Comment: is there a bundler executable within that directory?

Comment: try using the full path to the the bundle executable and running `(...path...)bundle install` in your rails app directory

Comment: Absurd: I get "Could not locate Gemfile"

Comment: You need to have a Gemfile present. Only a simple one with not much in it, I'm not sure on the minimal requirements. http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html EDIT: You should only need "source :rubygems" in it to get started.